# Adding a global variable to a javascript function so that it can be used on another php page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script that contains the following code:

```
$(function(){
var e=$.cookie("list_grid");
if(e=="g"){
    $("#products").addClass("smallGrid");
    $("#smallGrid").addClass("disabled")
    }else if(e=="l"){
        $("#products").addClass("largeGrid");
        $("#products").removeClass("smallGrid");
        $("#largeGrid").addClass("disabled")
        }else{
            $("#products").addClass("listGrid");
            $("#products").removeClass("largeGrid");
            $("#products").removeClass("smallGrid");
            $("#list").addClass("disabled")}});
$(function(){
            $("#smallGrid").click(function(){
            $("#products").fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(this).removeClass("listGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $(this).addClass("smallGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $(this).removeClass("largeGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $.cookie("list_grid","g")});
            $(this).addClass("disabled");
            $("#list").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#largeGrid").removeClass("disabled");
            return false});

            $("#largeGrid").click(function(){
            $("#products").fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(this).addClass("largeGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $(this).removeClass("listGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $(this).removeClass("smallGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $.cookie("list_grid","l")});
            $(this).addClass("disabled");
            $("#smallGrid").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#list").removeClass("disabled");
            return false});

            $("#list").click(function(){
            $("#products").fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(this).addClass("listGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $(this).removeClass("smallGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $(this).removeClass("largeGrid").fadeIn(300);
            $.cookie("list_grid",null)});
            $(this).addClass("disabled");
            $("#smallGrid").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#largeGrid").removeClass("disabled");
            return false})
            })
```

I need to add a var that can be used in some php code on another page. The purpose of this var is to know what listing type was selected so that i can trigger a specific type of output depending on what format the user requests to see the data in.

I tried to change

```
$("#smallGrid").click(function(){
```

to include the var as such

```
$("#smallGrid").click(function(){
var listingStyle="small"
```

but when i echo the contents of $listingStyle in my php code it is empty.
The site can use global vars and they are set like

```
$GLOBALS['variable_name'] = 'this string';
```

but i don't seem to be able to get a javascript var into a php global var

If anyone has any suggestions it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: To set something from your client code on your server you need to communicate with it using a HTTP request. Either use an AJAX call (preferably) or submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

> > but i don't seem to be able to get a javascript var into a php global var

That's correct, you can't do something in Javascript and have it *somehow* show up in PHP.  You *can*, however, use Javascript to set a `GET` variable in the URL which will then be populated into the `$_GET` array which you then use in PHP to store in the `$_SESSION` array so that it is then available to all other pages which can access the session.  You could also submit a `POST` so and used the `$_POST` array, but that's preferential or subject to the conditions of your site/program.

Answer (score 0):

**use session...**

First include **jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery.session.js**

TO STORE:

```
        $(function() {
             $.session.set("myVar", "Hello World!");
        });
```

TO READ:

```
        $(function() {
            alert($.session.get("myVar"));
        });
```

use:

```
print_r($_SESSION); //to check what are the sessions created...
```

more reference [here](http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/create-session-with-jquery/)

Comment: My understanding is that localStorage does not send anything back to the server but keeps it on the local machine. If that is the case then the solution would not work.